# The differences of "setInterval" between chrome and other browsers, Why?

Tags: javascript

### CODE *1*

```js
console.log('start');

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('setInterval');
}, 0);

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('setTimeout 1');
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('promise 3');
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('promise 4');
        })
        .then(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('setTimeout 2');
                Promise.resolve()
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log('promise 5');
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log('promise 6');
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    });
            }, 0);
        });
}, 0);

Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('promise 1');
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('promise 2');
    });
```

The result of this code on *Windows Edge*/*Mac Safari*/*Opera* browsers is as follow:

```
start
promise 1
promise 2
setInterval
setTimeout 1
promise 3
promise 4
setInterval
setTimeout 2
promise 5
promise 6
```

But when ran on chrome on Windows or Mac, the result have two cases.

Sometimes the result is same as above.
Sometimes the result outputs two `setInterval` as follow:

```
start
promise 1
promise 2
setInterval
setTimeout 1
promise 3
promise 4
setInterval
setInterval
setTimeout 2
promise 5
promise 6
```

I'm confused about the result.

### CODE *2*

```js
function expendTime(k){
    console.log((new Date()).getTime());
    while(k < 10000){
        for(var j = 2; j < k; j++){
            if(k%j == 0){
                break;
            }
            if(j == k-1){
                console.log(k)
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    console.log((new Date()).getTime());
}

var t = setInterval(expendTime,15,3);
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(t);
},30);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

The result of this code when ran on chrome and others browsers is different.

I consider the result on other browsers is correct, since it is coincides with my common sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking for help, please take the time to format and indent your code in a consistent, readable way. (It's a good idea when *not* asking for help, too.) I've done it for you on this occasion.

Comment: Are you assuming that a zero interval will make it synchronous? That is not the case if you are.

Comment: Re "Code 2": *"This result of this code when it run on chrome and others browsers is different."* What are you seeing in each case? What do you think is the common sense version?

Comment: I would guess that all the other libs use some kind of recursive `setTimeout` to emulate `setInterval` while Chrome uses something else (if that behaviour can really be reproduced)

Answer (score 2):

Yes [chrome's* implementation of `setInterval`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/Timer.cpp?rcl=e6d900fb6ed08dbd3a048899f38962ee75f4d8d0&l=162) does self-correct itself so its calls do fire at exact intervals, removing any drift.
*<sub>and maybe Edge's one ?</sub>

Here is an example code which does implement such a drift-correcting setInterval method, ran in chrome, you can see it has the same effect than the builtin one, while other implementations and recursive setTimeout will keep growing the drift.

```js
// drift-correcting setInterval
// returns an object which "_id" property is the inner timeout id, so it can be canceled by clearInterval
function driftCorrectingInterval(cb, delay) {
  var begin = performance.now(), // what time is it?
    result = {
      _id: setTimeout(inner, delay)
    },
    passed = true; // a flag to avoid try-catch the callback
  return result;

  function inner() {
    if (!passed) return; // 'cb' thrown
    passed = false; // set up the callback trap

    var now = performance.now(),
      drift = (now - begin) - delay;
    begin += delay; // start a new interval

    result._id = setTimeout(inner, delay - drift);
    // call it at the end so we can cancel inside the callback
    cb();
    passed = true; // didn't throw we can continue
  }
  
}


// snippet-only tests
function test(ms) {

  function setTimeoutLoop(cb, ms) {
    function loop() {
      cb();
      setTimeout(loop, ms);
    }
    setTimeout(loop, ms);
  }

  var now = performance.now(),
    built_in_prev = now,
    timeout_prev = now,
    sCI_prev = now,
    built_in_elem = document.querySelector('#test_' + ms + ' .delay.built_in'),
    timeout_elem = document.querySelector('#test_' + ms + ' .delay.timeout'),
    sCI_elem = document.querySelector('#test_' + ms + ' .delay.sCI');

  setInterval(() =>  {
    var now = performance.now(),
      delay = (now - built_in_prev) - ms;
    built_in_prev += ms;
    built_in_elem.textContent = Math.round(delay);
  }, ms);

  setTimeoutLoop(() => {
    var now = performance.now(),
      delay = (now - timeout_prev) - ms;
    timeout_prev += ms;
    timeout_elem.textContent = Math.round(delay);
  }, ms);

  driftCorrectingInterval(() =>  {
    var now = performance.now(),
      delay = (now - sCI_prev) - ms;
    sCI_prev += ms;
    sCI_elem.textContent = Math.round(delay);
  }, ms);

}

test(1000);
```

```css
[id^='test'] {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0 12px
}
```

```html
<div id="test_1000">
  <p>built in setInterval drift: <span class="delay built_in">0</span>ms</p>
  <p>built in setTimeout loop drift: <span class="delay timeout">0</span>ms</p>
  <p>driftCorrectingInterval drift: <span class="delay sCI">0</span>ms</p>
</div>
```

Note that [current specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timers) read as Firefox's implementation, and as what you understood, i.e a recursive setTimeout, without any consideration for drift.

Indeed the [*timer initialization steps*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps) requires that when the *repeat* flag is set to true, the same arguments should be passed to the next *timer initialization steps* method.

But an [open issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3151) discusses this very problem and *might* lead to a revision of the specs so that UAs are encouraged to apply such drift-correction when possible.

Comment: I think this answer is good for me, pls don't remove. I am reading it. now@dippas

Comment: Related: What they're all *supposed* to be doing: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#timer-initialisation-steps

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There is an [open issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3151) which might lead to a change in the specs. Didn't had time to go through all comments yet, so I'm not sure in which way the current discussion tends though. But I found that instead of *delay* I should have used *drift*, will edit tomorrow with these notes.