# Node.js setInterval() timing/scheduling alternatives

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to develop a Node.js server that acts as a metronome (sends a repeated timing message) for everybody connected. I have `socket.io` rooms working so clients can "subscribe" to different metronomes, but sync between them drifts wildly. I've been using multiple `setInterval()` calls to schedule timing messages, and I understand that it isn't a very reliable clock source:

Client:

```
const socket = io('localhost:8000', {});

socket
    .on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connected');
    })  
    .on('message', function(payload) {
        console.log(payload);
    });

// window.max is specific to the Max/MSP web browser object.
// This basically just subscribes to room 'inst0' or 'inst1'.

window.max.bindInlet('subscribe', function(inst) {
    socket.emit('subscribe', inst);
});
```

Server:

```
io.sockets
    .on('connection', (socket) => { 
        console.log('max connected!');
        socket
            .on('subscribe', (payload) => {
                console.log('subscription: ' + payload);
                Object.keys(socket.rooms).forEach(key => socket.leave(key));
                socket.join('inst'+payload);
            });
    });

setInterval(() => {
    io.to('inst0').emit('message', 'bang');
}, 500);
setInterval(() => {
    io.to('inst1').emit('message', 'bang');
}, 250);
```

Are there other strategies for event scheduling like this? In a latency-free world the messages would have sample-accurate timing (44.1kHz resolution), but I'd be ecstatic to get something even around 30Hz.

Comment: I don't know node that much, but if the problem of setInterval is the drift, then you can correct it in a setTimeout loop, like [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115731/50115944#50115944) (you'd probably have to replace performance.now with a node equivalent or Date.now() though). Also, I didn't tested any, but there seems to be some node's WebAudioAPI implementations. If they did it well, you should be able to have your 44.1KHz from there. (look at [AudioScheduledSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode)).