# Accurate timer with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, settimeout, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to build an accurate timer with javascript. My first try was using setInterval(), and of course it was a disaster. Then I tried to use requestAnimationFrame(), with the following code:

```
const startTimer = () => {
    let startedTime = Date.now()
    let now
    
    const insideTimer = () => {
        now = Date.now()
        if (now - startedTime > 1000) {
            setSeconds(prev => prev - 1)
            startedTime = Date.now()
            startTimer()
        } else {
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                insideTimer()
            })
        }
    }

    insideTimer()
}
```

I was very happy with the result, but turns out that when I go to another tab the timer stops, so my happiness went away.

Now I dont know how I should implement this, I tried doing it with while loops but couldn't make it work.

And I tried using setInterval() and checking every 20ms if the time difference of the Date variables is > 1000 but it seems to work exactly like the normal setInterval (I really didn't understand why)

I still want to use Date, because I think it is the best way to do it, how would you guys do it?

Comment: This seems very inefficient, how does other code perform while this is running? Where is *setSeconds* defined? What is *prev*? *requestAnimationFrame* runs at the screen refresh rate, so faster for faster screens.

Comment: What's wrong with `setInterval`? rAF is like the worst timer you could think of (right after `requestIdleCallback`). If you want a drift free version of `setInterval` everywhere (Chrome offers one out of the box), then implement one yourself with recursive `setTimeout()` calls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115731/the-differences-of-setinterval-between-chrome-and-other-browsers-why/50115944#50115944 If you need to tie to the event loop faster than every 4ms (but I doubt it since you're happy with rAF), then there are other task scheduling APIs you could use.